# Merge two Android projects so that both will appear on layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have an Android project with two modules.

One is for banner advertisement and the other is my application.

How to merge these projects so that the **banner ad** will show on every xml layout of my project?

Comment: You could just use <include> in all of your xml files and set your banner parent to <merge>

Answer (score 0):

I think best way would be creating the BaseActivity which extends Activity.
Create banner adview from java code. Then extend BaseActivity for other activities you are using.

Here's some sample code for BaseActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        createBanner();
    }

    void createBanner() {
        //handle banner creation here
    }
}
```

If you are using fragments for navigations you just have to declare banner inside the activity's layout xml

Comment: thank u..but actually i have made 2 different applications.
one is for banner ad which is showing banner ad on layout and other one is my application on which i want to show banner ad on this.then what should i do for implementing this.